# Boolean union and solids compenetration

Tags: modifiers

What is the difference between a boolean union of two solids and to left them compenetrated ? Visually I see no difference, but if I don't execute the union, internal faces remain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Boolean joins the two objects into a single mesh, with no inside faces, and no intersecting edges. This is important if you're trying to create a manifold mesh, or don't wan't overlapping faces. Of course when using union there is no visual difference, since the meshes are being added and the total surface remains...